# Different hover effects on hover from: left, right, top, bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I think I might have a very difficult question.
I am making my portfolio website and now i have a question about the hover effect for my portfolio item's.
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w31us88h/)

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="item-hover">

  </div>
</div>
```

In the fiddle when you hover an item the hover div comes from above.

Now my question is: I want the hover div to appear from the side that you hover the div from.
So if you hover the div from the left the hover-div will appear from the left. And if you hover the div from the right the hover-div will appear from the right. And the same thing for top and bottom.

I hope someone can help me with my problem!

Greets,
Boaz Poolman

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, what you need to do is the following;

1. Create Parent container for an item
2. Create an inner element that will be the hover effect with a width: 0 and height: 0;
3. Check the direction of the mouse
4. Based on the direction, add a class to the inner element that changes it's hover effect (width for x, height for y)

To capture the direction of the mouse, when the user first hovers in to your element, you need to capture it's position. After a very short amount of time, capture the position again. Compare these two positions, and you'll be able to get the direction from which the mouse entered the element. For example;

If the initial mouse position for the element was `x: 5` and `y: 10` and the new position is `x: 20` and `y: 10`, you can extrapolate that the mouse moved in the `rightward` direction.

Here is a tutorial that guides you through what you need to know;

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

And here is the demo;

http://tympanus.net/TipsTricks/DirectionAwareHoverEffect/